# LeetCode: Flood Fill, Recursion in For Loop stuck in endless loop

Tags: python, recursion

I was working on this specific LeetCode problem and I encountered a problem where I would be stuck recursing. The way I understand it, if an input type is mutable, the input should be pass by reference, so they should be referencing the same thing. Can someone explain how my method breaks? I really want to try solving this problem using recursion, but I don't understand how to do it using my method. My code first finds north, east,south,west, and then determines if they are valid. It then determines if among those directions if they have the same count as the original node.

Of those that have the same count as the original node, I need to recurse on those and repeat the process until all nodes have the value of newColor

https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/

```
class Solution:
    def floodFill(self, image: List[List[int]], sr: int, sc: int, newColor: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        top = (sr-1, sc)
        down = (sr+1, sc)
        left = (sr, sc-1)
        right = (sr, sc+1)

        # Possible Directions
        posDirec = [direc for direc in [top,down,left,right] if direc[0] >=0 and direc[1] >=0 and direc[0] < len(image) and direc[1] < len(image[0])]
        # Neighbors that we can traverse
        posNeigh = [e for e in posDirec if image[e[0]][e[1]] == image[sr][sc]]
        image[sr][sc] = newColor

        # print(image, '\n')
        print(len(posNeigh), posNeigh, image)
        if len(posNeigh) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            for neigh in posNeigh: #top, down,left, right of only valids
                self.floodFill(image, neigh[0], neigh[1], newColor)
        return image
```

At the very end, my program should return the image. I want to return the image at the end, however, my code ends up stuck in recursion

Comment: You should include what this code does in the description as well as examples of input and expected output specially given the absence of docstrings which is not a good practice as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following line:

```
# Neighbors that we can traverse
posNeigh = [e for e in posDirec if image[e[0]][e[1]] == image[sr][sc]]
```

This condition fails to account for the possibility that `image[e[0]][e[1]]` has already been filled in with `newColor`, resulting in an infinite loop between filled cells and a stack overflow.

If we change it to

```
posNeigh = [
    e for e in posDirec 
    if image[e[0]][e[1]] == image[sr][sc] 
    and image[e[0]][e[1]] != newColor # <-- added
]
```

we can make sure we're not revisiting previously-filled areas.

---

Given that the list comprehensions have grown quite unwieldy, you might consider a rewrite:

```
def floodFill(self, image, sr, sc, new_color):
    target_color = image[sr][sc]
    image[sr][sc] = new_color

    for y, x in ((sr + 1, sc), (sr, sc - 1), (sr, sc + 1), (sr - 1, sc)): 
        if y >= 0 and x >= 0 and y < len(image) and x < len(image[0]) and \
           image[y][x] != new_color and image[y][x] == target_color:
            self.floodFill(image, y, x, new_color)

    return image
```

Answer (score -1):

A mutable input does not pass by reference. The way I see it, solving it using recursion is not possible. Try an iterative solution.

Comment: This isn't correct--the problem can be solved with recursion and `image` is a local variable which is an object reference to the original list (that is, reassigning it wouldn't affect the original scope, but mutating it would).